# Only checked specific checkbox inside a loop with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, my issue is when I click ***Select All*** I want just want this row's checkbox to be checked. The 1st image below is the initial state that I want when the event click on `.give-all-permissions` fires. I want to be the 2nd image but my it gives me the 3rd image output how to achieve like 2nd image. Please see all the images that I tried to get this to work.

#### 1st img

[image: 1st image]

#### 2nd img

[image: 2nd image]

#### 3rd img

[image: 3rd image]

### my HTML markup

```html
<div class="row permission-group">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <fieldset class="mt-1 {{ $loop->last ? null : 'mb-1' }}">
       <div class="checkbox checkbox-shadow">
          <input type="checkbox" class="give-all-permissions" id="module_{{ md5($module->id) }}">
          <label class="cursor-pointer" for="module_{{ md5($module->id) }}">Select All</label>
       </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    @foreach ($module->permissions as $permission)
       <fieldset class="mt-1 {{ $loop->last ? null : 'mb-1' }}">
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-shadow">
             <input class="checked-input" type="checkbox" id="permission_{{ md5($permission->id) }}">
             <label class="cursor-pointer" for="permission_{{ $permission->id }}">{{ $permission->name }}</label>
          </div>
       </fieldset>
    @endforeach
  </div>
</div>
```

### my code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.give-all-permissions').click( (e) => {
                    // e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target.checked === true) {
        $('.checked-input').each(function (i, el) {
           el.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
           this.checked = true;
        });
     } else if (e.target.checked === false) {
         $('.checked-input').each(function (i, el) {
             el.removeAttribute("checked");
             this.checked = false;
         });
     }
  })
})
```

Comment: `$(e.target).closest(".permission-group").find(".checked-input").each...`

Comment: Also see [Tree Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you brother it works ❤

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm facing an issue here, an issue that when I click another checkbox instead of `Select All` and then if I click `Select All` it doesn't work anymore can u give any solution on that, please